# Fastest way to delete all files in large volume in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance

I want to completely clear the content of a very large Linux volume containing a huge number of small files.  I know how to delete files, but just doing a for loop that calls delete on each one is very slow.

I'd just send a command down to bash to use bash tools, but were running in a docker alpine Linux container, so all the tools I would use don't exist.  I suppose I could change the docker file to ensure their there but that's feeling a bit ugly.

Comment: Can you use a multi-stage build to give you access to the commands you need to delete the files using bash tools?

Comment: Apologies if I'm missing something obvious, but does your Alpine container not have `rm`?

Comment: @esqew it does, I don't know if that's any faster then using python though.  I wanted to use rsync which has been benchmarked to be much faster but that doesn't exist.

Comment: @dsollen "*I don't know if that's any faster then using python though.*" Any reason why you don't want to benchmark it against any of your other options? "*I wanted to use rsync*" I'm not aware of `rsync` being used solely as a utility to delete items from a filesystem; are you sure you have a full understanding of `rsync` and what it's used for? Again, I may be misunderstanding or otherwise missing something here, so please do correct me if necessary.

Comment: Since you want to kill the whole volume, presumably you could unmount it and reformat it? Most of the data isn't truly *gone* (disk recovery tools could get it), but it's generally much faster if you don't force it to zero out the disk (it just replaces the existing file table with a new one representing an empty disk). Generally requires root to do it though.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I see your idea, but part of me is afraid to try that in kubernettes in case it meses up it's mounting magic lol

Comment: @dsollen: Well, reformatting without fully zeroing the partition is the only way to delete all files from a volume in roughly `O(1)` time. All other solutions are just microoptimizations on the same technique: Recursively listing all files and directories and deleting them recursively. Sure, delegating a massive deletion operation to `rm -rf` might be a titch faster than the within-Python `shutil.rmtree`, simply because `rm` is implemented in C, where `shutil.rmtree` is implemented in Python (slow storage media probably means they're not that far apart), but they're both still `O(n)`.

Comment: If reformatting isn't an option, I'd just use `shutil.rmtree`; it might be a little slower than delegating out to `rm -rf`, but either one is largely I/O bound no matter what (meaning faster code doesn't matter much), and at least if something goes wrong, you can get useful exceptions with detailed causes from `shutil.rmtree`, where delegating out to a subprocess of any kind means your ability to detect, describe and recover from errors is much more limited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about speed of this, but I guess you could try if you wanted.

Here is an example of how you could use `shutil.rmtree` to delete the contents of a directory:

```py
import shutil

# Replace '/path/to/dir/' with the path of the directory you want to delete contents from
shutil.rmtree('/path/to/dir/')
```

This function will delete all subdirectories and files. It is important to use this function with caution, as it will delete the all contents permanently.